# Finding a word in a text file

Tags: c#, list, file-io

So I have a large file text file, one that is 12,970 lines long. Within this insanely large data file I have two groups: one that is called A and one that is called S. A starts at line 1 and ends at line 7678. S starts on the next line and ends at line 12,970. I need to make a program that will look at these two groups and search for how many times the word "Processed" appears in the file. I have a piece a code I thought would work, however every time I run it, I am getting 0 as the number of processed. Please help figure out what the problem is and an alternate solution to find it.

```
var lines1 = File.ReadLines(path);
List<string> a = lines1.Take(7678).ToList();
List<string> s = lines.Skip(7678).Take(5292).ToList(); //5292 is the number of 
var aCount = a.Count(line => line == "Processed"); //lines that are in
Console.WriteLine(aCount); //group s, just for clarification on what it means
```

Comment: Will the entire line be `"Processed"`?  You might looks for lines that _contain_ or _start with_ `Processed` in the debugger and see if there's any embedded non-visible characters that is throwing off your equality check.

Comment: You create lists called `a` and `s`, but then do the count on `apollo`.  What is `apollo`?

Comment: Did you try debugging?  You place breakpoints in your code and inspect the values of variables at runtime.  It's super convenient for figuring out why trivial stuff doesn't work.

Comment: @juharr not quite sure what apollo is actually. I made the edits on the question

Comment: @DStanley each line has the word "Processed" in it. There are a bunch of other words and numbers in the line, but the code itself is looking just the word processed in the line, not the other stuff

Comment: @PatrickOvermyer You're testing if the entire line is just "Processed" when it sounds like you want to test if it contains that word `line => line.Contains("Processed")`

Comment: `line == "Processed"` means lines that exactly contain "Processed", nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @juharr That makes sense looking at that code. Do you have an idea on how I can change it?

Comment: ReadLines() returns an IEnumerable, you are iterating that one twice. It would be a good idea to use ReadAllLines() instead, on this moderately small file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for lines where the *entire line* is equal to `"Processed"`.  From your comment it sounds like you only want lines that *contain* `Processed`, which can be done by using [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
var aCount = a.Count(line => line.Contains("Processed"));
```

Comment: Isn't that the exact same line of code that is on top? Because according to @juharr comment it is looking for the entire line to equal, which is wrong. Unless you are saying to do something else

Comment: Yes @juharr proposed the same thing; he chose to do it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: OK just clarifying that it was and not something different. Now my next question is what is the syntax that I need to be using for this String.Contains? Is it like a.Contains("Processed") or is it something different?

Comment: @PatrickOvermyer I've given you the syntax (and a link to the documentation with examples) - is it not working for you?

Comment: Now it is after a meddled with it a little bit. Thank you so much for your assistance